# How to update a UISegmentedControl which is inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

Each row of a table has a position control implemented as a segmented control.  When the table is initialized, the selectedSegment is unknown.  I want to update the `selectedSegment` from a different function.

Currently the code creates an array of `segmentControls` which can be accessed by a function.  The program runs OK, but the `segmentControl` does not updated.

Here is the code to create the table cells:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.shades[indexPath.row]

    let shadePositionControl = UISegmentedControl (items: [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Icon-Closed").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal),
                                                       #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Icon-Half").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal),
                                                       #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Icon-Open").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)])
    shadePositionControl.frame = CGRect(x: cell.bounds.origin.x + 200, y: cell.bounds.origin.y + 6, width: 90, height: 30)

    shadePositionControl.tag = indexPath.row
    shadePositionControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.shadePositionControlAction), for: .valueChanged)
    shadePositionControls.append(shadePositionControl)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(shadePositionControl)
    return cell
}
```

and here is the function to update the selectedSegment:

```
func statusPoll() {
    myShade.getShadow() //gets the state from AWS-IOT
    if myShade.gotState() {
        let shadeIndex = 0  //hard-coded during proof-of-concept testing
        let position = myShade.getDesiredState(key: "position") as! String
        switch position {
            case "closed": shadePositionControls[shadeIndex].selectedSegmentIndex = 0
            case "half": shadePositionControls[shadeIndex].selectedSegmentIndex = 1
            case "open": shadePositionControls[shadeIndex].selectedSegmentIndex = 2
            default: shadePositionControls[shadeIndex].selectedSegmentIndex = -1
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing to have the segmentedControl get updated, and have the view refreshed to reflect the update?  Is there a better way to update the per-cell segmentControl than creating an array of them?  I tried using shadeTableView.reloadData() to refresh the display of the segmentedControl, but it had no effect.

Comment: It's best to reload the tableview or else you will have to keep a copy of cell to update it's segmented control but that is not safe because of reusing of cells.

Comment: you could create a pointer object to that segmented control and update your pointer object

Comment: cellForRowAt will be called multiple times when you scroll the tableview, your approach doesn't respect that and not applicable in the case.

Answer (score 0):

This method of updating controls in a table cell works.

The reason it didn't appear to work was there was a bug in instantiating the shadePositionControls array.  It was instantiated as follows, which added an unwanted segmentedControl at the zero position of the array.

```
var shadePositionControls = [UISegmentedControl()]
```

Hence, the code in statusPoll was updating the bogus segmentedControl, not the intended one.

The fix was change the array creation to:

```
var shadePositionControls:[UISegmentedControl] = []
```